# I need help understanding train_test_split?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, train-test-split

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
```

I have a question about the train_test_split function from sklearn. First, why do we split the data??? and were do we get the testing data from. Do we just chop the data in half and use some of it to train and some of it to test?? Than doesn't make sense since the data is already filled. If it is filled, then what are we predicting now?? I need help!

Comment: Google "overfitting"

Comment: I don't understand?

Comment: Lookup "overfitting" and that will answer your question.

Comment: so, is the testing data already filled with columns?

Comment: if it is, then why are we using the testing data? the answer is already there

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Read about [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) (particularly [how to create a good example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) in order to get responses.

Comment: My understanding is that the training data and the testing data are the same, except that the testing data has less data and the training data has more

Comment: The training data is used when training your model and the testing data is used to evaluate a trained model... If you just have a pool of data, then you can split it into a training data chunk and a test data chunk.

Comment: so testing data = training data?

Comment: Literally just google "training data vs test data" and read [the wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Training,_test,_and_validation_sets).

Comment: This is a basic statistics question and has nothing to do with the programming aspects of using `scikit-learn`. Please direct it to the proper Q&A site, in this case [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1):

> First, why do we split the data???

We split the data to isolate a portion of it for validation purposes. Use the non-isolated portion to fit the algorithm and use the algorithm to test again the isolated portion.

> were do we get the testing data from.

The testing data is actually part of your original dataset.

> Do we just chop the data in half

We usually chop at the 20-40% mark.

> If it is filled, then what are we predicting now??*

You are actually not trying to predict the result directly. You are training the algorithm to fit the training set and use the testing set to see how accurate the algorithm is.

Answer (score 0):

Your original dataset should be split up into training and testing data. For example, 80% of the data could be used for training and 20% could be used for testing. The data is split so that there is data for the model to be evaluated on to see how well the model performs on unseen data.

- **Training:** This data is used to build your model. E.g. finding the optimal coefficients in a Linear Regression model; or using the CART
  algorithm to create a Decision Tree.
- **Testing:** This data is used to see how the model performs on unseen data, as it would in a real world situation. This data should
  be left completely unseen until you would like to test your model to
  evaluate performance.

**Extra notes on validation data:**

To tune your model (for example, finding the best *max_depth* value for a decision tree) the training data should also be proportioned into training and validation data. K-Folds Cross Validation can be used here. The model should be trained on the training data and evaluated on the validation data. This is performed multiple time with cross validation.

The results (e.g. MSE, F1 etc.) can then be evaluated on each fold and  used to tune the hyperparameters. By using cross-validation to tune the hyperparameters, this ensures that the model is not overfitting to the test data.
Once the model is tuned, it can then be applied to the test data.